# Improving performance of the App on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am relatively new Android developer. I made a social gifting app using facebook api and 
is not very heavy in terms of images and data. However, it displays e-gift cards using web view.  I have improved its performance by implementing the following steps.

1: Using MVC pattern to construct activities.
2: Using image caching.
3: Using java's URLConnection http calls rather than apache's http client.
4: Using Drawable to fill colors rather than using images.
5: Making light REST backend calls specifically for mobile.

I was wondering if you guys can suggest simple, effective ways to improve the performance of an Android app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some great tools that come with the SDK/device to help you with this.

- Keep your view hierarchy as shallow as possible [**Hierarchy Viewer**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) is a great tool for this
- Use [**TraceView**](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to see what methods are taking the longest to execute
- Optimize your code with [**Proguard**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)
- Use [**monkey**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) and [**Strict mode**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to see if you have any long running processes on the main
- Fix all [**lint**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html) errors and warnings